# Prevent Adobe CreativeSDK plugin from saving the edited file automatically

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

How to Prevent Adobe Creative SDK plugin from saving the edited file automatically in android?

When i try to edit the image, the file is automatically saved to device.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to avoid saving the image, but you can set where it is saved using the `AdobeImageIntent.Builder()`'s `.withOutput()` method. Example:

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
    .setData(uri) // input image source
    .withOutput(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/my-pic-name.jpg")) // output file destination
    .build();
```

Whether you set the location using `.withOutput()` or not, you will get back the saved image's `Uri` in your `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {


            /*
               `1` being an arbitrary int we used as a requestCode
                when starting the `imageEditorIntent`
            */
            case 1:

                // Do things, for example:
                Uri editedImageUri = data.getData();
                mEditedImageView.setImageURI(editedImageUri);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to store the data long term, you might use that `Uri` to go back and delete the saved image when you are done with it.